# Is it permitted for a minyan to daven outdoors?

Tags: halacha, tefilla

The weather in New York is beautiful recently. It crossed my mind to daven outside in the glory of HaShem's beautiful Creation.

Is it permissible to daven outdoors?

Comment: See last line of [Berachos 34b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%91) **and Rashi**

Comment: @ShmuelBrin ... and _Tosafos_. And _SA OC_ 90:5. And _Mishna B'rura_. Why don't you post it as an answer? Sounds like one.

Comment: One can only daven outside if one can daven better there. Like if there is a disturbance or its too hot. http://www.shoresh.org.il/spages/shut/shut679.htm. What is considered davening better is a matter of opinion. It is similar to davening at home instead of in shul. There must be a RMF about this somewhere. Although these two cases may not be exactly linked since one is at least davening with minyan outside.

Comment: uv'lechtecha baderech and discussions of workers praying (at least saying shma) in trees (halachot 2 and 4 http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912953/jewish/Chapter-Two.htm) lead me to ask what the possible issurim are. While there are aome limitations, the concept of "outside" isn't assur.

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6_%D7%94

Comment: Presenting anecdotal evidence, when I ran the New York marathon in 1990, we had a minyan that morning, outside at the starting line area.  So, I cannot imagine why we cannot daven outside.

Comment: @Dennis Because you saw it once, you can't imagine anyone holding otherwise in different situations?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point.  I was only pointing out 
an example of an orthodox minyan that was held outdoors.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37406/759

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes (see Mishna Berura on Shulchan Aruch 90:5 [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=238) and an explanation thereof [here](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_digest/Chelek_1/0222_Siman_90_Seif_4-7.pdf)). As evidence of this, regular minyanim were organized outdoors at a recent Chabad Lag Ba'Omer carnival.

Nevertheless, Shulchan Aruch forbids davening in:

- A building (or construction zone) that might collapse
- A place where there is excrement or a bad smell

It is *favorable* to daven in a place designated for davening or for learning Torah. But, there is nothing wrong with impromptu davening outdoors (especially if a minyan is present).

Comment: See also _Shulchan Aruch_, _Orach Chayim_ 90:5.

Comment: (link to the above http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=238 )

Comment: Ahh I see now what you're saying. Did you by any chance get a moment to look up the source msh210 quoted? I provided a link to it in my above comment.

Comment: the m"b cited (11) gives guidelines for where outdoors one may pray (under trees is better than in an open field). Since other than the Zoharic reference, the codified law is not "one may not pray outside" but only "one may not pray in an open area like a field" one may infer that other outdoors places are viable as long as they conform to the rules.

Comment: @leefogel I don't see why you accepted this answer which leaves out important qualifications.

Comment: @DoubleAA I feel the Shulchan Aruch and Mishnah Berurah thereof are sufficient answers to my question. Thanks for your constant participation!

Comment: -1 The sources you link say the exact opposite of what you claim.

Answer (score 4):

From: http://dinonline.org/2012/07/11/davening-outdoors/

> The Gemara (Berachos 34b) writes that it is wrong (arrogant — chatzuf) to daven in an open field.
>
> Rashi explains that in an open field, one doesn’t feel fear of the
>   King, and one doesn’t pray with a broken heart. Tosafos, however,
>   understands that the concern is for passers-by, who are liable to
>   disturb a person’s davening.
>
> The Magen Avraham (90:6) rules that the problem is that davening
>   outside makes a haughty statement: “Even though there are passers-by,
>   they will not disturb my intent in davening!” This is arrogant and
>   wrong.
>
> The Shulchan Aruch (90:5) rules that one should not daven in an open
>   place, and the Mishnah Berurah (11) adds that those who are always
>   traveling can daven in an open place, but should try to daven
>   by a tree.
>
> Therefore, although it is not forbidden to daven outdoors, it is wrong
>   to daven in an open area, and one should seek a sheltered place.

Additional details are brought [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCwQFjACahUKEwjq-f_b7YHJAhXIFx4KHe2DBNc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fisrael.aish.com%2Fsmicha%2FRavCableSugyos%2FHilchosTfilah%2FReview%2520Sheet%2520for%2520Makom%2520Hat%27filah.doc&usg=AFQjCNEGat3OKYX0hKWV6wQAx8DQiendbw&sig2=xn8J6S_4zVdNTINuYd7Cgw&cad=rja):

> **Level of Priority**
>
> Pri Megadim/ Mishnah Brurah (90:10): If a person had a choice between
>   davening in a house with no windows or outside he should daven in the
>   house. Davening with windows is a nice mailah whereas davening in a
>   wide open area is an issur.
>
> **An Area With Walls But No Roof**
>
> Sharei T’shuvah (90:1): He brings a string of poskim who all agreed
>   that an area with walls is enough to meat the requirements of this
>   Gemara even though it has no roof!
>
> **Travelers**
>
> Magen Avraham (90:6)/ Mishnah Brurah (90:11): A traveler who is in a
>   hurry and must daven on the side of the road may do so. There is no
>   chutzpah involved here since this person has no choice but to daven
>   where he is.
>
> Chayeh Adam/ Pri Megadim / Mishnah Brurah (90:11): Even for a traveler
>   it is preferable to find a semi-secluded place (i.e. amongst some
>   trees etc.).